# Delete directory after moving files from it [Java]

Tags: java, file, directory, nio

I have a **directory** `M:\SOURCE` from which **I have listed and moved it's contents until it is empty**

**After that, I want to go ahead and delete it**, I have tried (yes I also made sure it was empty):

```
sourceFile being "M:\SOURCE"

sourceFile.delete()
Files.delete(sourceFile.toPath());
FileUtils.deleteQuietly(sourceFile);
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(sourceFile);
FileUtils.forceDelete(sourceFile)
```

*There are no exceptions being thrown* by any of the other methods and .delete() returns `true`
HOWEVER, the directory still exists and *when trying to access the folder* I get the following message from windows:

[image]

**When running process explorer** I can see that java is using that resource (**This only happens when I try to delete the source**, and bear in mind that trying to delete source directory is the last thing my program does)

[image]

And just to make me freak out even more, **once I stop my java virtual machine**, THEN the folder magically disappears. So Java did got the instruction right, it's just that is not willing to delete it until it's terminated

Running `System.gc()` before deleting the directory **also didn't help, and my working directory is not the one I'm trying to delete**

Comment: Did you had any files in the folder that were deleted in your java program ? if you did some I/O operations maybe the files are hanged intro your JVM mem. you need to close them/it.

Comment: L.E. how you move the content? Can you share code ?

Comment: Some of those methods return result values ... which you should be checking.  Also, I'd have thought you should be using the NIO APIs to do this rather than Apache Commons.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this problem when using `Files` NIO calls which list or return a Stream of directory contents before deleting the directory.

Using try with resources on any Stream of Path returned by Files NIO can help prevent this issue:

```
try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(directory)) {
    // do any work on contents - move / delete
}
// delete directory after closing stream above
```

Comment: Unfortunately I already made sure to do that. I have a stream that I turn into a List<Path> and then I close it immediately after; in order to iterate over the list an avoid this kind of problems